# Maven Command Line Args in the settings.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven, repository

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to find out whether there is a possibility to outsource Command Line Args in the Settings.xml.

I can't use the MAVEN_OPTS Env-Var and the .mavenrc file, but i need the Settings in every project. It is important that no plugins are used which are not included after the installation (the settings are needed for a connection with the repository).

Settings:

```
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=VALUE
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=VALUE
 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=VALUE
 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=VALUE
 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=VALUE
 -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=VALUE
 -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=VALUE
 -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=VALUE
```

I hope i haven't overlook somthing obvious...
Thanks in advance,
LocXar

EDIT-1: Maven Version: `Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)`

EDIT-2: I have tried it like this, but it does not work: `<javax.net.ssl.trustStore>VALUE</javax.net.ssl.trustStore>`

Comment: Afaik the settings.xml have nothing to do with actually running any maven jobs, just setting up the maven environment...

Comment: Which Maven Version do you use?

Comment: Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best thing is to use the `${maven.projectBasedir}/.mvn/maven.config` if you like to use special configurations elements for Maven itself (for example: `-T3 ..`). Furthermore you can use things for the JVM via `${maven.projectBasedir}/.mvn/jvm.config` which means in your case you should use the `jvm.config` with the following content:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=VALUE
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=VALUE
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=VALUE
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=VALUE
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=VALUE
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=VALUE
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=VALUE
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=VALUE
```

So you can put that in your project and check in this within your project. So this makes `.mavenrc` and `MAVEN_OPTS` superfluous. This is documented in the [Release Notes for Maven 3.3.1](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html).

But I have to say that you like to set the above system properties I got the impression you would like to ignore the certificates within an https connection which does not makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your worries, but the last 3 properties are only for testing. Your answer is really good! Is there a possibility to set the properties for all projects?

Comment: If those last are only for testing than you should configure maven-surefire-plugin appropriately ....If you wan't to have them for all projects use `MAVEN_OPTS`.....

Comment: Thanks for the fast and exact answer.

Comment: I tried several ways, but at the end it is MAVEN_OPTS. See here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html

Comment: @Barny: I tried as in https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.htmll  .  I created a file named mavenrc_pre.bat. But when i build a project in command line i get error as MAVEN_OPTS not recognized as internal or external command. I have set MAVEN_OPTS in user variable, Restarted the system and tried. But I still get same error. Any idea, Where I am going wrong?

Comment: How does it look like?

Comment: If you use a `.bat`, try `SET MAVEN_OPTS="..."`, I think the guide uses Bash / Linux.

Comment: `maven.config` is no batch file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems me you can define all arguments in Maven Settings profile with properties:
https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Profiles

HIH

Comment: i have tried it like this, but it does not work.

<javax.net.ssl.trustStore>VALUE</javax.net.ssl.trustStore>

Comment: maybe they could fix this in a new release...